# Why do we use web services in java instead of jsp-servlet technology?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Why do we use web services in java instead of jsp-servlet technology as both serves same purpose?

Comment: both dont serve same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

JSP generates HTML that view for **Human**.

Web services returns data that sort of view for **Machine**.

Answer (score 2):

Both don't have the same purpose. You could use a web service API to serve the content of your JSPs. So the JSPs interact with your web services. This is just one way of implementing it.